# Nested tables, remove inner table containing pattern

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I have again an issue with scoping (I guess). I want to write an as generic as possible function to retrieve a page and remove some of its code before I set its content to a placeholder (`<DIV>`)

Below a sample code of the loading page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>testtesttest</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/AJAX/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/util.js'></script>

<body>
<div class='contentcontainer'>
<hr>

<div class='contentitem' id='restart' style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px; display:block;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src='/images/warn__xl.gif'></td>
            <td><p style="font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; color:#02A3C1;">Loading: please wait...</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class='contentitem' id='ready' style="margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 100px; margin-bottom: 100px; display:none;">
         <div id="content">
         </div>
</FORM>
</div>


</div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
        var content = $("#content");
        //var content = $("#ready");

    //hide loading bar
    function hideLoading(){
        loading.fadeTo(1000, 0);
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){   
       content.load('/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html div .contentitem', function(content) {
       //$(this).find('table:not(:first-child)').css("font-style", "italic"); //just need to replace the css by remove() to remove what is italic.
       $(this).find('table:eq(2)').css("font-style", "italic"); //just need to replace the css by remove() to remove what is italic.

        /*$(this).find('table:contains("Content Based"):first-child').each(function(i){
                   //.css("display", "none");
                    //  tabelle[i] = $(this).attr("onChange");
              //$(this).attr("id",i)
              alert(i);
          });*/

        $(this).find('tbody').each(function(){
              //$("tr").children("td").find('table:contains("Content Based"):first-child').each(function() {$(this).css("font-style", "normal");});
              $("tr").children("td").find('table:contains("Content Based")').each(function() {$(this).css("background-color", "yellow");});
              //$("tr").children("td").find('table:contains("Content Based"):first-child').each(function() {$(this).remove();}); 
          });
        document.getElementById("restart").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("ready").style.display = "block";
        //alert('Load was performed.');
    });
    });

  //intelligent version of submitform: will only refresh what was needed:
   (function() {  
   // 
   var proxied = submitForm;
   submitForm = function(theForm, actionNo, flags, primkey, confirmMsg, anchor, eval_code, customP) {
   //potential issue with the switch language... I think actionNo = 0 means reload.
   //alert('gotcha');
   // Function submit a form
        $.ajax({
            //type: theForm.attr('method'),
            //type: get,
            //url: theForm.attr('action'),
            //content.load('/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html div .contentitem', function(content) {
            url: "/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html",
            //data: theForm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
                var dataHTML = $(data).html().filter("div .contentitem");
                $(dataHTML).find('table:eq(2)').css("font-style", "bold"); //just need to replace the css by remove() to remove what is italic.
                content.html(dataHTML); 
            }
        });

  }
   return false;
   })();

</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

And an excerpt of the loaded page:

```
<HTML>
<HEADER>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/util.js'></script>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <div class='contentcontainer'>
        <hr>
        <div class='contentitem'>
            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <tr>
                    <td class='icon' valign='top' width='100px'><img src='/images/webf__xl.gif' alt='Parental Control'></td>
                    <td class='data' valign='top'>
                        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td align='left'><span class='itemtitle'>Parental Control</span></td>
                                <td align='right'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan='2'>
                                    <p>This page summarizes the configuration of your Thomson Gateway regarding web site filtering. </p>
                                    <form name='SiteFilterCfg' action='/cgi/b/sfltr/cfg/' method='post'>
                                        <br>
                                        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td>
                                                <td valign='top'>
                                                    <span class='blocktitle'>Title</span><br>
                                                    <table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td width='30px'></td>
                                                            <td width='220px'></td>
                                                            <td width='50px'></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>Use Address Based Filter:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'><input type='checkbox' name='30' value='1'   ></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>Action:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'>
                                                                <select name='31' style='width: 270px'>
                                                                    <option value='0' >Block</option>
                                                                    <option value='1' selected>Allow</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='4' align='right'>
                                                                <input type='button' name='25' value='Apply' onClick='submitForm(document.SiteFilterCfg,25,0,"","",0,"")' >
                                                                <input type='button' name='26' value='Cancel' onClick='submitForm(document.SiteFilterCfg,26,0,"","",0,"")' >
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <p>Some text. </p>
                                                    <table class='edittable' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5' class='black'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='1' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='3' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th align='left'>Web Site</th>
                                                            <th align='left'>Action</th>
                                                            <th align='left'>Redirect</th>
                                                            <th colspan='2'></th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='3' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5' class='black'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='1' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='evenrow' colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='10' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='evenrow' colspan='5' align='center'><i>No filter rules defined.</i></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='evenrow' colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='10' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5' class='black'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='1' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='oddrow' colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='3' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='oddrow'><input type='text' name='32' maxlength='80' onkeypress='return noenter(event)'  style='width: 60 '></td>
                                                            <td class='oddrow'>
                                                                <select name='33' style='width: 60 '>
                                                                    <option value='0' selected>Block</option>
                                                                    <option value='1' >Allow</option>
                                                                    <option value='2' >Redirect</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class='oddrow'><input type='text' name='34' maxlength='80' onkeypress='return noenter(event)'  style='width: 60 '></td>
                                                            <td class='oddrow' colspan='2' align='right' valign='middle'><input type='button' name='19' value='Add' onClick='submitForm(document.SiteFilterCfg,19,1,"","",0,"")' ></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td class='oddrow' colspan='5'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='3' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td colspan='5' class='black'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' border='0' width='1' height='1' alt=''><br></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                    <br>
                                    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width='40' valign='top'><img src='/images/bull__md.gif' alt=''></td>
                                            <td valign='top'>
                                                <span class='blocktitle'>Content Based Filtering</span><br>
                                                <form name='ContentFilterCfg' action='/cgi/b/sfltr/content/cfg/' method='post'>
                                                    <table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td width='30px'></td>
                                                            <td width='220px'></td>
                                                            <td width='50px'></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>License Type:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'>None</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>License Expiration:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'>Unknown (server not yet contacted)</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>Use Content Based Filter:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'><input type='checkbox' name='30' value='1'   ></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width='170'>Action for uncategorised sites:</td>
                                                            <td colspan='3'>
                                                                <select name='31' style='width: 270px'>
                                                                    <option value='0' selected>Block</option>
                                                                    <option value='1' >Allow</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td></td>
                                                            <td valign='bottom' colspan='2'>Block all categorized websites</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </form>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height='7' colspan='4'><img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan='4' align='right'>
                                                <input type='button' name='10' value='Apply' onClick='submitForm(document.ContentFilterCfg,10,0,"","",0,"")' >
                                                <input type='button' name='11' value='Cancel' onClick='submitForm(document.ContentFilterCfg,11,0,"","",0,"")' >
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I want to remove the "second" table after `<span class='blocktitle'>Content Based Filtering</span>`. In the function I am not doing `remove()` but rather coloring it in yellow. It seems the whole page is yellow...
My feeling is that the "this" is not in the right scope.

Any idea how I can get the most inner table and just that one, not matching on all containing tables?

EDIT:

Thanks to Clav, I found a way to do that in the document ready function. Now, I'm trying to make the "submitForm" more clever, and refresh the div instead of reloading the page.

I thought I just needed to copy paste the code to make it work, but it did not work straight forward...

Here some excerpt of the code that works in the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
content.load('/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html div .contentitem', function(content) {
   $(this).find('tbody').each(function(){
   $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").parent("td < tr < tbody < table").css("background-color", "yellow");
   });
document.getElementById("restart").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("ready").style.display = "block";
});
});
```

But then if I do the same in the submitform (I use Ajax to submit):

```
(function() {  
   // 
   var proxied = submitForm;
   submitForm = function(theForm, actionNo, flags, primkey, confirmMsg, anchor, eval_code, customP) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html",
            // for test I do a get
      datatype: "html"
    })
    .done(function (html) {
                $(html).find('td').each(function(){
             $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").parent("td").parent("tr").parent("tbody").parent("table").css("background-color", "yellow");
          });
                content.html(html);
    })
    .fail(function (html) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
       }
   return false;
   })();
```

**It doesn't work.**
My understanding is that it is because the source code of cfg3.html doesn't contain the `<tbody>` tag. So I changed and loaded the html in the placeholder then modified it (I abandoned trying another hierarchy as it failed):

```
(function() {  
   // 
   var proxied = submitForm;
   submitForm = function(theForm, actionNo, flags, primkey, confirmMsg, anchor, eval_code, customP) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/AJAX/test/cfg_3.html",
            // for test I do a get
      datatype: "html"
    })
    .done(function (html) {
                content.html(html);
          content.find('tbody').each(function(){
             $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").parent("td").parent("tr").parent("tbody").parent("table").css("background-color", "yellow");
          });
            })
    .fail(function (html) {
        window.location.reload();
    });
       }
   return false;
   })();
```

My issue is that this works in Firefox but not in IE... I don't see why because basically I'm doing the same in submitForm as I was doing in `document.ready`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code that is coloring table cells yellow is looping over all table bodies on the document and the row selectors in that loop aren't scoped to any particular table, 
so really you're iterating over every table row in the document once for every table that is on the page. If I'm understanding you correctly and you want to get the `table` with the class `datatable` in the `form` immediately after the `span` containing the text "Content Based Filtering" you should be able to just do this:

```
$("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").next("form").children("table.datatable").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the relation is not that easy...
I found that this is working, although not nice IMHO:
'$("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").parent("td < tr < tbody < table").css("background-color", "yellow");'

Comment: Can you put a class on the parent table?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I currently test on my PC, but this is actually building a new interface on top of legacy SW (CGI generated pages).

Comment: My bad... The code above (previous comment) doesn't work.
what works is:
$("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").parent("td").parent("tr").parent("tbody").parent("table")...

Comment: Here how I finally did:<BR>'    content.find('table').each(function(){
     //var test345 = $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").closest("table");
     $("span:contains('Content Based Filtering')").closest("table").remove();
     // Filtragem com base em conteúdo
     $("span:contains('Filtragem com base em conte')").closest("table").remove();
     $(document).find("#restart").css("display","none");
     //alert(test345);
     content.css("display", "block");
    });
'